# Can you define sine and cosine in the complex numbers?

Tags: trigonometry, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-exponential

So I have been reading the paper "Thermalization for Perturbations of Dynamical Systems" by G. Barrera and M. Jara (you can find the paper [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.09207.pdf)) and there is a step that I don't quite understand in the proof of collorary 2.12 which states:

> Write $\gamma=\lambda +i \theta$, where $\lambda>0$ with $\theta \neq 0$. To the eigenvalue $\gamma$ we associated an [complex] eigenvector $u_1,u_2\in \mathbb{R}^2$. An straightforward computation shows:
> $$e^{\lambda t }e^{-Qt}x_0=(c_1 cos(\theta t) -c_2 sin (\theta t))u_1 + (c_1 sin(\theta t) +c_2 cos(\theta t))u_2$$
> for any $t\geq 0$, where $c_1:=c_1(x_0)$ and $c_2:=c_2(x_0)$ are not both zero. Notice that $c:=\sqrt{c_1^2+c_2^2}>0$ and let $cos(\alpha)=c_1/c$ and $sin(\alpha)=c_2/c$. Then
> $$e^{\lambda t }e^{-Qt}x_0=c cos(\theta t + \alpha)u_1+c sin(\theta t + \alpha)u_2$$
> for any $t\geq 0$.

Now, following what I believe the paper refers to as a "a straightforward computation" is that for dimention 2, if $Q$ has two complex conjugate eigen vectors $v_1=u_1-i u_2$ and $v_2=u_1+i u_2$, then   $$e^{\lambda t }e^{-Qt}x_0=\sum_{k=1}^2 e^{i\theta_k t}v_k=e^{i\theta t}(u_1-i u_2)+e^{-i\theta t}(u_1+i u_2)$$
But with this I conclude that $c_1=2$ and $c_2=0$ always. My question is, would this work if I had different coefficients in the sum? Say:
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^2 d_k e^{i\theta_k t}v_k=&d_1 e^{i\theta t}(u_1-i u_2)+d_2 e^{-i\theta t}(u_1+i u_2)\\
=&d_1(cos(\theta t)+i sin(\theta t))(u_1-i u_2)+d_2 (cos(\theta t)+i sin(\theta t))(u_1+i u_2)\\
=&[(d_1+d_2)cos(\theta t)-i(d_2-d_1) sin (\theta t)]u_1\\
&+[(d_1+d_2)sin(\theta t)+i(d_2-d_1) cos (\theta t)]u_2
\end{align}

then, would it be posible to choose $c_1=d_1+d_2$, $c_2=i(d_2-d_1)$ and $c$ and $\alpha$ as they did and continue the proof normally? In particular, having to deal with the $i$ in $c_2$ is the part confuses me.